# Run-time Expandable Listview with Edittext and Spinner

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, expandablelistview, android-spinner

My intention is to get data from the run-time growing listview (as shown in below figures) which has Edittext and Spinners and send this data to remote server using json.

Am I on the correct path or there is another kind of method to be used for this.

[image: Screen1]

I want to access Edittext and Spinner from the listview which is expanded at runtime.

[image: like this]

My Problem is, whenever a new view is added, it overlaps on the previous view.

[image: like this]

Instead, it should get added below the 1st view. (Solved this. See the edited code).

Another thing is how to access edittext & spinner from each view? I want to accept this data from user & save it in the device. How to do that? (in `private void SaveUserData() {}` method).

Below is my full code.

**Edited on 20 Mar 2018**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package tandel.amit.expandablelistview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
Button buttonSave;
FloatingActionButton fab;
Adapter adapter;
int count = 0;
String[] Heading = {"User 1","User 2","User 3","User 4"};
String Name = "Name";
String ID = "ID";
String Gender = "Gender";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    buttonSave = findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    fab.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    AddView(count++);
}

View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSave:
                SaveUserData(); // Save the data to Local Database
                break;
            case R.id.fabAdd:
                AddView(count++);  // Add new View in listview
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};

private void AddView(int i) {
    DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(Heading[i],Name,Gender,ID);
    adapter.add(dataProvider);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void SaveUserData() {

}
}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
package tandel.amit.expandablelistview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/*
 * Created by Amit Tandel on 2/2/2018.
 */

public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    List list = new ArrayList();
    public Adapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(@Nullable Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.list.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.list.get(position);
    }

    static class DataHandler{
        TextView Heading,Name,Gender,ID;
        EditText UserName,UserID;
        Spinner UserGender;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler();
        if (convertView == null){   // If row is empty, we need to create row
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            dataHandler.Heading = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading);
            dataHandler.Name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            dataHandler.Gender = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGender);
            dataHandler.ID = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvID);
            dataHandler.UserName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.etName);
            dataHandler.UserID = convertView.findViewById(R.id.etID);
            dataHandler.UserGender = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spGender);
            convertView.setTag(dataHandler);
        }else {
            dataHandler = (DataHandler) convertView.getTag();   // If row already present then get that row
        }
        DataProvider dataProvider;
        dataProvider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
        if (dataProvider != null) {
            dataHandler.Heading.setText(dataProvider.getHeading());
            dataHandler.Name.setText(dataProvider.getName());
            dataHandler.Gender.setText(dataProvider.getGender());
            dataHandler.ID.setText(dataProvider.getID());
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**DataProvider.java**

```
package tandel.amit.expandablelistview;

/*
 * Created by Amit Tandel on 2/2/2018.
 */

public class DataProvider {
    private String Heading;
    private String Name;
    private String Gender;
    private String ID;

    public DataProvider(String Heading, String Name, String Gender, String ID) {
        this.setHeading(Heading);
        this.setName(Name);
        this.setGender(Gender);
        this.setID(ID);
    }

    public String getHeading() {
        return Heading;
    }

    public void setHeading(String heading) {
        Heading = heading;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return Gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        Gender = gender;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="tandel.amit.expandablelistview.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
n
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Save" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="User 1"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGender"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Gender"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spGender"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ID"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Still unable to figure out how to get values from the child items (            dataHandler.UserName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.etName);
            dataHandler.UserID = convertView.findViewById(R.id.etID);
            dataHandler.UserGender = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spGender);) of the list view so that I can store them on remote server using Json.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated with respect to this query. You can just give me link of similar solution.

My intention is to get data from the run-time growing listview (as shown in above figures) which has Edittext and Spinners and send this data to remote server using json.

Am I on the correct path or there is another kind of method to be used for this.

Comment: After searching a lot on the internet, I found that Edittext should not be used in Listview as when your list grows, the Edittext loses focus & values contained in it due to recycling of the list items.

Now I am looking for another solution for this problem instead of expandable listview. You can suggest the proper direction.

Thanks in advance for the help!